# How do I install Preon?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, preon

I am trying to install preon and run it within IntelliJ.

I have downloaded the source code from https://github.com/preon/preon.

Then I open the project with IntelliJ.

Then I download pecia and import it as a module into the preon project.

Then I try to run the BitmapFileTest program at ...preon-master/preon-samples/preon-sample-bmp/src/test/java/org/codehaus/preon/sample/bmp/BitmapFileTest.java

Here are the first few errors that I get:

...preon-master/preon-el/src/main/java/org/codehaus/preon/el/Expressions.java

- Error:(151, 24) java: cannot find symbol   symbol:   class
  LimboWalker   location: class org.codehaus.preon.el.Expressions
- Error:(154, 9) java: cannot find symbol   symbol:   class LimboLexer 
  location: class org.codehaus.preon.el.Expressions
- Error:(154, 32)
  java: cannot find symbol   symbol:   class LimboLexer   location:
  class org.codehaus.preon.el.Expressions
- Error:(156, 9) java: cannot
  find symbol   symbol:   class LimboParser   location: class
  org.codehaus.preon.el.Expressions
- Error:(156, 34) java: cannot find
  symbol   symbol:   class LimboParser   location: class
  org.codehaus.preon.el.Expressions
- Error:(160, 9) java: cannot find
  symbol   symbol:   class LimboWalker   location: class
  org.codehaus.preon.el.Expressions
- Error:(160, 55) java: cannot find
  symbol   symbol:   class LimboWalker   location: package
  org.codehaus.preon.el

For some reason the compiler cannot find the Limbo classes in its own project.

What do I need to do to be able to build and run this sample project?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that these classes are generated by ANTLR from `Limbo.g` and
`LimboWalker.g`, but IntelliJ doesn’t automatically know how to use ANTLR to build them.

There is an ANTLRWorks plugin for IntelliJ that supports ANTLR version 3,
but it was last updated in 2009 and doesn’t seem to work in IntelliJ 13.

There is a newer “ANTLR v4 grammar plugin” that is actively maintained, but
it is only for ANTLR 4, and preon is still on ANTLR 3.

But the Maven plugin for ANTLR is stable and can build it.

What you need to do is: right-click preon-el in Project, then choose the
Maven → Generate Sources and Update Folders menu option. This will call
the Maven plugin to generate `LimboWalker.class` from `LimboWalker.g`, among other things.

Then choose Build → Make Project, and the `BitmapFileTest` will run.

Comment: Thank you Andrew, your answer solved my problem.  Thank you!  I have another question.  I have read about references to Preon 2.0 which includes both and encoder and a decoder as well as ability to analyze a hex dump.  Am I using the latest V2.0?

Comment: @ClarkS It doesn’t look like 2.0 was ever built. Current github version is 1.1, no commits in over a year, no new features in over two years. If you’re interested, [contact the developer](http://stackoverflow.com/users/136476/wilfred-springer).